# React shorthand condition outputting wrong data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can React not handle multiple && conditions with its shorthand conditional syntax?  I've been banging my head on this one issue that makes no sense to me.  I have a conditional where I only want to put the data if **defaults** is equal to true and **familyDeductibleMultiplier** equals a number, but for some reason, even when this condition should not be fulfilled, it's still being fulfilled, therefore the select is empty.

```
if (item.name === 'familyDeductibleMultiplier') {
  return (
    <div key={item.name} className='form-row'>
      <label>{item.desc}</label>
      <select
        name={item.name}
        onChange={gatherFormData}
        onBlur={fillNextInput}
      >
        {!defaults && <option value='0'>-Select-</option>}
        {defaults &&
          typeof familyDeductibleMultiplier === 'number' && (
            <option value={familyDeductibleMultiplier}>
              {familyDeductibleMultiplier}
            </option>
          )}
        {/* {item.filler !== undefined &&
          item.filler.map(item => {
            return (
              <option key={item.index} value={item.index}>
                {item.desc}
              </option>
            );
          })} */}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As of now, even when **familyDeductibleMultiplier** is equal to 'undefined' and **defaults** is equal to 'true', that line is what's being output.

**Update**

This is where I'm collecting the value for familyDeductibleMultiplier.

```
if (item.type === 'Long') {
  this.arr.push({ [e.target.name]: parseFloat(e.target.value) });
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: parseFloat(e.target.value),
  });
}
```

Comment: have you tried a tenary operator ?

Comment: React shorthand syntax uses something similar to the ternary operator and if that condition is valid, the output is the JSX.

Comment: Are you by any chance using `parseInt() / parseFloat()` to convert **familyDeductibleMultiplier**  to a number?

Comment: Yes, I'm using parseFloat().

Comment: You can absolutely use multiple conditions in the shorthand syntax. I would check your react dev tools or just throw in some logs to clarify why that condition isn't true.

Comment: `typeof parseFloat(undefined)` would still return `number`. Would be helpful to see the code where you're making the conversion.

Comment: I've now updated my post to show where the data is being collected for that specific variable.

Comment: If your `event.target.value` for **familyDeductibleMultiplier** is already `undefined`, using `parseFloat()` on it will change the `undefined`'s type to a `number` and your shorthand condition will yield to `true`. **Edit** You could try avoiding `parseFloat()` if the value is already `undefined`.

Comment: So, the defaults variable is the setting to prefill specific inputs in the form first, before you ever start filling things out.  Therefore, **familyDeductibleMultiplier** would equal `undefined` but **defaults** would equal `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (item.type === 'Long') {
     // event.target.value here is undefined
    this.arr.push({ [e.target.name]: parseFloat(e.target.value) }); //using parseFloat() on that undefined changes the type of undefined to number (even if it's undefined)
      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: parseFloat(e.target.value),
      });
    }
```

so when your `default` is `true` and you check for **familyDeductibleMultiplier** (whose value is `undefined`) to be a number, it is going to be a number because of that `parseFloat()` and that line still will be the output. Hope this helps.